# i am trying to upload multiple images using dio mathod and multipart but its giving error

Tags: flutter, api, dart, multipart, dio

when i print _images list it shows that 'instance of multipart' and when i send list of imageFileList this doesn't accept by server.

also what is the use of multipart in sending images?
here is the response error from server response from server error 500

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

var token;

Dio dio = Dio();
List<dynamic>? _images = [];
var apiURL = 'https://denga.r3therapeutic.com/public/api/addpost';
FormData formData = FormData();
Future<String> adminAddproperty({
  title,
  address,
  price,
  area,
  bedrooms,
  bathrooms,
  parking,
  other,
  description,
  List<File>? imageFileList,
  context,
}) async {
  for (int i = 0; i < imageFileList!.length; i++) {
    var image = imageFileList[i].path;

    _images!.add(
        await MultipartFile.fromFile(image, filename: image.split('/').last));
  }

  FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
    'title': title,
    'address': address,
    'price': price,
    'area': area,
    'bedrooms': bedrooms,
    'bathrooms': bathrooms,
    'parking': parking,
    'others': other,
    'description': description,
    'images[]': imageFileList,
  });

  SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  token = pref.getString('token');
  print('AdminApisToken =$token');
  print('_images');

  Response responce;

  responce = await dio.post(apiURL,
      data: formData,
      options: Options(headers: {
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer $token",
      }));
  print('Responce: $responce');
  return '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar situation and I solved it by adding the content type to the `MultipartFile`, something like this:

```js
await MultipartFile.fromFile(picture.path, contentType: MediaType.parse(image.mimeType)
```

Or hardcoding the type `MediaType('image', 'jpeg')`. The `MediaType` is part of the `package:http_parser/http_parser.dart` package.

Hope it helps!

Comment: when i print by the given line this is the output /flutter (13103): imageFileList: [File: '/data/user/0/com.example.rent_house/cache/scaled_image_picker4651270268225022962.jpg']
I/flutter (13103): _images: [Instance of 'MultipartFile']

Comment: May the problem be related with this typo when creating the _formData_ `'images[]': imageFileList`? Try using `'images': imageFileList` instead